# How to get a tripple self-join working

Tags: mysql, self-join

I am trying to self join information from a table, to show a hierarchy (the table contains members, which consist of  children and their parents). The table name is ‘*members*’, the four important columns are *id, full_name, father_id* and mother_id. The id's in the columns father_id and mother_id match the corresponding id's in column 'id'. As a result of the query, I would like to have a table with three columns, with column names 'Name', 'Father' and 'Mother'

I searched google, w3 schools and stack overflow, the closest to what I was looking for was a topic I found right here, called ‘Explanation of self-joins’ that had the following example code:

```
select
  c1.Name , c2.Name As Boss
from
  emp1 c1
inner join emp2 c2 
  on c1.Boss_id = c2.Id
```

I altered the query as follows (I didn't even dare include the third column yet :') ):

```
select
  c1.full_name as Name, c2.full_name as Father
from
  members1 c1
inner join members2 c2 
  on c1.father_id = c2.id
```

Unfortunately, I got an error message stating the following: 1146 - Table 'ppstb.members1' doesn't exist

I guessed it had something to do with how I simulated having two tables. The next thing I experimented with is:

```
select
  c1.full_name , c2.full_name as Father
from
  members c1, members c2
inner join members c2 
  on c1.father_id = c2.id
```

But this also gives an error: 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'c2' What step am I missing?

Comment: For #1146 error: Table names are case-sensitive. Are you using correct case?

Comment: @Arulkumar according to his queries his table name is members but he used its name as members1 in that query that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

last member should be c3 not c2

```
select
  c1.full_name , c3.full_name as Father
from
  members c1, members c2
inner join members c3 
  on c1.father_id = c3.id
```

Comment: you dont need that "members c2" you can remove it if you want

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the code working, using left-joins. I'm not sure why the inner joins wouldn't work, but this solved my problem:

```
SELECT 
  members.full_name, b.full_name AS Father, c.full_name AS Mother 
FROM 
  members  
LEFT JOIN 
  members b ON (members.father_id = b.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
  members c ON (members.mother_id = c.id)
```